# InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type for generic repository

Tags: c#

> Generic Repository throwing following error.
>           nvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Core.Repository.MongoDb.MongoRepository`1[Controllers.HomeController+TestUser]' while attempting to activate 'Controllers.HomeController'.

the following is the generic repository which is throwing error while trying to do the dependency injection.

```
      public interface IEntity
        {

            string Id { get; set; }

            DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        }

   public interface IRepository<T> where T: IEntity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Inserts the specified entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">The cancellation token.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Task<T> Insert(T entity, InsertOneOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));
}

 public class MongoRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
 {
          ....
  }


public class Entity: IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    ....
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IRepository<TestUser> _repository;

    public class TestUser : Entity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public HomeController(MongoRepository<TestUser> repository)
    {
              this._repository = repository;

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result=_repository.GetAll();

        return View(result);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs class registered service like this.

```
 services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(MongoRepository<>));
```

basically, it is not even coming to Home controller before itself throwing the error. when I try to instantiate without DI the repository works not sure why it's failing in DI.

Comment: Your IRepository<T> expects IEntity<T>, while your actual entity TestUser (which you use in constructor) inherits only from Entity and does not implement IEntity<T> interface. Is that a problem?

Comment: Please take the time to [edit] your question so that the code is formatted correctly.

Comment: @Jure the Entity class implements the IEntity interface and I am deriving my other classes from Entity but not sure why it is not able to resolve in DI?

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting

```
MongoRepository<TestUser> repository
```

Or you have to use the Interface, it's the principle of the DI.

Replace in the constructor of your controller by the following

```
IRepository<TestUser> repository
```

And It will works.

Comment: figure it out basically the default constructor is deleted accidentally causing the MongoRepository object was not created in DI process

Comment: I don't understand what was your trouble.. Glad to hear that it's working now.